# laravel: how to set smtp settings from database

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

i want to use data stored in database for set smtp port,user,pass,host in controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

Config::set('mail.host', DB::table('settings')->find(4)->val);
Config::set('mail.username', DB::table('settings')->find(2)->val);
Config::set('mail.password', DB::table('settings')->find(3)->val);
Config::set('mail.port', DB::table('settings')->find(5)->val);

if($request->email_test !== null) {
    Mail::send(new MailTesting());
    }
}
```

but mail config set from .env
when remove this line from env:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=9ed941b3d4e2d6m
MAIL_PASSWORD=d13ea2a29a5ceem
```

i show this error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied"
```

how to resolve this problem

Comment: On your database table settings, you have also same mailtrap credentials?

Comment: @sta yes........

Comment: Give the value and try like `Config::set('mail.port', 587);` 
 and let me know the result

Comment: `Config::set('mail.host', 'smtp.mailtrap.io');
    Config::set('mail.username', '9ed941b3d4e2d6');
    Config::set('mail.password', 'd13ea2a29a5cee');
    Config::set('mail.port', 2525);`
 default load config from .env and when remove env show this error:
`Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys in `Config::set()` do not correspond to the keys in the `config\mail.php` (default standard file), try changing the keys to correspond to the standard default file

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{

    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', DB::table('settings')->find(4)->val);
    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', DB::table('settings')->find(2)->val);
    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', DB::table('settings')->find(3)->val);
    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', DB::table('settings')->find(5)->val);

    if($request->email_test !== null) {
        Mail::send(new MailTesting());
    }
}
```